# Return node parameter from Neo4j graphclient query

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I would like to find items from the same brand but from a different category. 
And then return their id's.

In my database I currently have the following nodes: Item, Brand, Category.

And relations: IN_CATEGORY, FROM_BRAND.

The Items have properties: id, brand and category.

I have created this query, which return the correct result

```
MATCH (i1:Item {Id:"5"})-[r1:FROM_BRAND]->(b:Brand)<-[r2:FROM_BRAND]-(i2:Item) 
WHERE i1.category <> i2.category 
RETURN i2.Id
```

I don't know if it is possible to avoid using the category property and instead use the IN_CATEGORY relation.

My problem is now that I would like to perform the query using the Neo4j graphclient.

By now I come this far:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetIds(string itemId){
  var query = _client.Cypher
    .Match("(i1: Item)-[r:FROM_BRAND]->(b:Brand)<-[rr:FROM_BRAND]-(i2:Item)")
    .Where((Item i1) => i1.id == itemId)
    .AndWhere((Item i1, Item i2) => v1.category != i2.category)
    .Return(i2 => i2.As<Item>());

  return query.Results;
}
```

Its seems to return the correct items. But I would like to return the item ids, not the whole items.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using WITH

```
var query = _client.Cypher
    .Match("(i1: Item)-[r:FROM_BRAND]->(b:Brand)<-[rr:FROM_BRAND]-(i2:Item)")
    .Where((Item i1) => i1.id == itemId)
    .AndWhere((Item i1, Item i2) => i1.category != i2.category)
    .With("i2.id AS iId")
    .Return(iId => iId.As<string>());

    return query.Results;
```